What is the view that Universe itself is not a compendium of things but a single entity?
The definition of the Universe as the sum of all that exists, seems to imply that human beings have created this term ‘Universe’ to be a catch-all term for all that exists. What I was suggesting is that it is more accurate to conceptualize the Universe as a single ‘entity’ with infinite moving parts, as opposed to just a conceptual tool used to refer to all that exists.
For example, instead of saying “Human beings exist in the Universe”, we would state that “Human beings exist as a part of the Universe”.
Is there a philosophical position that reflects this view? I have often heard Monism (but that seems to be a general sentiment that can be applied to any field such as epistemological or substance monism) and what I am looking for is a philosophical system that essentially states that all that exists is one thing.

Just a note in case you don't get a good answer, but this has been discussed quite a bit in philosophy going back to pre-Socratic philosophers. Today, such discussions sometimes come up in the context of meriology.

Consider looking in to Nonduality.

You may like Spinoza whose philosophy can be characterized as God = Universe = Nature. Keyword you may want is pantheism

There are two that seem to be a good fit for your question:
Advaita Vedanta is a Hindu school of thinking that sees the self as the same as the universe.
Process Philosophy imagines a universe that experiences itself through the lens of things that exist.
Check those out and see if they meet your needs!

‘Parmenides held that the multiplicity of existing things, their changing forms and motion, are but an appearance of a single eternal reality (“Being”), thus giving rise to the Parmenidean principle that “all is one.” From this concept of Being, he went on to say that all claims of change or of non-Being are illogical. Because he introduced the method of basing claims about appearances on a logical concept of Being, he is considered one of the founders of metaphysics. Plato’s dialogue the Parmenides deals with his thought.’
https://www.britannica.com/biography/Parmenides-Greek-philosopher
